# Jank free experience and websocket

Tags: javascript, performance, websocket

This is a use case I have encountered several times and I wonder if there is anyway of getting a smooth loading animation while receiving data.

When the app starts a CSS animated div loader is shown. 
Then we start receiving a bunch of messages from websocket pushing in the initial data set. Its not that big, maybe ~60 < 1k messages.

That makes the animation to jank since the time spent in javascript is way over the 16ms 60fps goal.

As far as I understand `websocket.onmessage` is a blocking call.

Is there anyway of spreading those onMessage events in several `frames`?

[image]

**CSS anim**

```
.loader-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}  

.loader {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    animation: load4 1.3s infinite linear;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

@keyframes load4 {
    0%,
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 0.2em @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 0 @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 0 @bluejeans;
    }
    12.5% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 0 @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 0.2em @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 0 @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans;
    }
    25% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -0.5em @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 0 @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 0.2em @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 0 @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans;
    }
    37.5% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 0 @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 0.2em @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 0 @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans;
    }
    50% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 0 @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 0.2em @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 0 @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans;
    }
    62.5% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 0 @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 0.2em @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 0 @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans;
    }
    75% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 0 @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 0.2em @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 0 @bluejeans;
    }
    87.5% {
        box-shadow: 0 -3em 0 0 @bluejeans, 2em -2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 3em 0 0 -1em @bluejeans, 2em 2em 0 -1em @bluejeans, 0 3em 0 -1em @bluejeans, -2em 2em 0 0 @bluejeans, -3em 0 0 0 @bluejeans, -2em -2em 0 0.2em @bluejeans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be several solutions:

1. If you load that data in a Web Worker the data can be received on a separate thread and not interfere with the main thread's work.
2. Make sure your CSS animation only manipulates transforms and opacity. This way there's good chance it will run on a separate thread.
3. Load the initial data in a single XHR (a.k.a AJAX request) instead of rapid 60 separate messages.

You can also mix the above together.

Comment: I will try the webworker way. 2) is already the case and 3) is not applicable. I want to keep only one stream of communication. Thank you!

Comment: yer welcome! i do strongly recommend you change that initial load with a single request or a special "sync" message. you're probably having much more overhead this way which may also cost you more

Comment: can you edit and add your animation code to the question?  or at least a simplified example of it?

Comment: Done, does box-shadow falls in to the `opacity/transform` thread?

Comment: No, on the other hand, box-shadow is a very "heavy" property to draw and usually degrades performance on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the above answer:

> If any animation triggers paint, layout, or both, the “main thread”
>   will be required to do work. This is true for both CSS- and
>   JavaScript-based animations, and the overhead of layout or paint will
>   likely dwarf any work associated with CSS or JavaScript execution,
>   rendering the question moot.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/animations/animations-and-performance

To check what css style trigger the main thread.

http://csstriggers.com/

[image]

Comment: Tested and confirmed! This is great stuff!